# Expire check boxes cookies on click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, checkbox, jquery-plugins

I have multiple checkboxes in datatable with the one name and different values i can store cookie for all checkbox in checked by the following code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('value'));
    if (mycookie && mycookie == "true") {
        $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
    }
});
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {

    var date = new Date();

    var uncheckDate = new Date();

    // to expire cookies after one day if checked
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    // to expire cookies after 1  seconds  if unchecked 
    uncheckDate.setTime(date.getTime() + ( 1 * 1000));

    $.cookie($(this).attr("value"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
    path: '/',
    expires:  date
    });

    $.cookie($(this).attr("value"), $(this).prop('unchecked'), {
    path: '/',
    expires:  uncheckDate
    });  
  });
});
```

Also i can expire the cookie for each checkbox if unchecked

**But I need use button for example expireButton to expire All checkboxes that checked.**

How I can achieve that ?

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as below:

```
$('.expireButton').on('click',function()
{
   var uncheckDate = new Date();
   uncheckDate.setTime(date.getTime() + ( 1 * 1000));
   $.each($('input[type=checkbox]:checked'),function(){ //Get all the checked checkbox
        $.cookie($(this).attr("value"), {
               path: '/',
               expires:  uncheckDate
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks  Guruprasad Rao for your answer , but when i clicked the expireButton i seen this error in console, can help me please

TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj 
typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj;

Comment: @JustUser.. Updated my answer.. Kindly check!! You need to use `$` in `.each` to get all the `checked checkbox` as `$.each($('input[type=checkbox]:checked')....`

Comment: thanks   Guruprasad Rao    , it's working with but after adding this line  
`$.cookie($(this).attr("value"), $(this).prop('checked', false) { ......`
thanks again

Comment: OK. I was thinking `prop checked` statement is not required here.. Anyways happy coding.. :)